# How to spawn a number of threads async to call a method multiple times in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to call a worker method multiple times to load data into a database. I want to do some parallelism with this and be able to specify the number of threads to use. I thought of using the mod operator to split the workload, but getting stuck on how to implement with `async` `await`.

So the async method must create `n` number of threads and then call the worker method so there are `n` streams of work happening in parallel. The worker method is synchronous.

I had a go at it, but quite sure how to implement what I want. Is there a pattern for this?

Some code I was playing around with:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestingAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int threads = 3;
            int numItems = 10;
            Task task = ThreadIt(threads, numItems);
        }

        static async Task ThreadIt(int threads, int numItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Item limit: {numItems}, threads: {threads}");
            for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Adding item: {i} mod 1: {i % threads}. ");
                int task = await DoSomeWork(i%threads, 500);
            }
        }

        static async Task<int> DoSomeWork(int Item, int time)
        {
            Console.Write($"    Working.on item {Item}..");
            Thread.Sleep(time );
            Console.WriteLine($"done.");
            return Item;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm going to rephrase because maybe I wasn't clear in my requirements.

What I want is to create `n` number of threads. There will be `x` number of items to process and I want them to be queued up using `mod` (or something else) and then processed in order in parallel across the `n` threads. When one item has finished, I want the next item to be processed **immediately** and not wait for all three threads to finish. **Some items will take longer to process than others**, maybe even up to 10 times longer, so other threads should not be waiting for one of the threads to complete.

For example if we have 3 threads and 9 items, this would happen:

```
thread1: items 0,3,6 
thread2: items 1,4,7
thread3: items 2,5,8
```

each thread processes it's workload in order and does not wait in between each item.

Comment: Just as a note, you might want to watch out because [tasks are (stil) not threads](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/)

Comment: `async`/`await` don't do what you seem to think they do. And for loading data into a database, it's usually better to *minimize* the number of parallel I/O activities that you're trying to run. Look for e.g. bulk insert instead.

Comment: @MindSwipe ok how should I tackle this?

Comment: Also for testing, you might want to use `Task.Delay(time)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(time)` because Thread != Task

Comment: Try the `Parallel` class, let me try something

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad did a good job. Looks like the `Parallel` class wasn't needed after all.

Comment: Take a good look at your DbConnection: a) it is not thread-safe, open 1 per thread b) Parallel will only be faster when your SQL server can handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a `List<Task<T>>` and start them and then `await` it with `WhenAll` if you want all tasks to be completed or `WhenAny` if any of them completes:

```
static async Task ThreadIt(int threads, int numItems)
{
      List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
      Console.WriteLine($"Item limit: {numItems}, threads: {threads}");
      for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
      {
           Console.Write($"Adding item: {i} mod 1: {i % threads}. ");
           tasks.Add(DoSomeWork(i%threads, 500));
      }

       var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

and when using `Task`, `async` and `await` we should be using `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`:

```
static async Task<int> DoSomeWork(int Item, int time)
{
      Console.Write($"    Working.on item {Item}..");
      await Task.Delay(time); // note this 
      Console.WriteLine($"done.");
      return Item;
}
```

EDIT:

You can create a `ConcurrentQueue` and then dequeue each time when 3 Tasks complete and generate next 3 like:

```
static async Task ThreadIt(int threads, int numItems)
{
      ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
      Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ForEach(x => queue.Enqueue(x));
      List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
      Console.WriteLine($"Item limit: {numItems}, threads: {threads}");
      while (!queue.IsEmpty)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
          {
              if(queue.TryDequeue(out int val))
              {
                   Console.Write($"Adding item: {val} mod 1: {val % threads}. ");
                   tasks.Add(DoSomeWork(val%threads, 500));
              }
          }

       var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
     }
}
```

Comment: @MindSwipe it will run the task in async manner in thread pool

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the entire thing finishes instantly. The Task.Delay should block but it's not.

Comment: @MarkAllison we need to `await` it like: `await Task.Delay(time);`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks but it's not behaving like I want. I want each thread to process an item, and when finished get the next item. Not wait until all threads are finished. So a maximum of three threads running at the same time at any moment.

Comment: @MarkAllison i have added second code sinppet in which showed how it can be done which might be helpful

Comment: @EhsanSajjad appreciate your time, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MarkAllison the later code snippet will execute three items and then will load next three and execute them

Comment: Hi @EhsanSajjad that's not the behaviour I need. Some of the items may take 10x longer to process than others, so I need other threads to complete their work and get the next item rather than wait for thread1 to process its large item. Does that make sense? I made another edit to hopefully make it clear.

Comment: Then you most likely need to implement the "wait one-by-one" pattern. https://nemetht.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/waitallonebyone-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

> I need to call a worker method multiple times to load data into a database. I want to do some parallelism with this and be able to specify the number of threads to use... The worker method is synchronous... Is there a pattern for this?

Yes, the Task Parallel Library.

Given:

```
static int DoSomeWork(int Item, int time)
{
  Console.Write($"    Working.on item {Item}..");
  Thread.Sleep(time);
  Console.WriteLine($"done.");
  return Item;
}
```

You can parallelize it as such:

```
static List<int> ThreadIt(int threads, int numItems)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Item limit: {numItems}, threads: {threads}");
  var items = Enumerable.Range(0, numItems);
  return items.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(threads)
      .Select(i => DoSomeWork(i, 500))
      .ToList();
}
```